# Has anyone got an example of how to add "google adsense for ajax" to a web page?

Tags: adsense

I would like to use google adsense for ajax to a web page but I can not find any example code. I already have a google adsense publisher ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature has been discontinued

[Note: We're no longer accepting new applications for AdSense for AJAX but we appreciate your interest in the product and will continue to work on new ways to monetize dynamic content.](http://code.google.com/intl/cs/apis/afa/)

Comment: Do you know the business reason why it was discontinued?